# Angular : Addons its not allowed

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular-cli

I am following a tutorial to make a website using angular on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zEvzW_sSXk0&list=PL4G8-yGhsH5YR8IOmjRjslw3gDLBaEU_5&index=4&t=304s). 
I get this error when adding addons in `angular.json` on 8:17 like this:

> Schema validation failed with the following errors:
>     Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(addons).

Is this because I add "addons" on `angular.json`, while the tutorial is adding "addon" on `angular-cli.json`?

There is no `angular-cli.json` on my directory.

I'm prety sure I am following the tutorial 100%. I think the structure between `angular.json` and `angular-cli.json` is the same:

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.scss",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss"
],
"addons": [
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/*.+(otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)"
],
"scripts": []
```

Answer (score 0):

`addons` was removed from the config according to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/4052).

Check [the docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/include-font-awesome.md) on how to include `font-awesome`:

> **Using SASS**
>
> Create an empty file _variables.scss in src/.
>
> Add the following to _variables.scss:
>
> `$fa-font-path : '../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts';`
>
> In styles.scss add the following:
>
> `@import 'variables';`
>
> `@import '../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';`